# How to use useEffect to change boolean values

Tags: react-native, boolean, use-effect, react-hook-form, react-native-elements

I have 2 user text inputs called Search Location and Coordinates. I'm trying to use a checkbox when selected allows search location to be edited and the coordinates input be disabled and vice versa when the checkbox is not selected.

When i first run the code, i can edit Search Location and Coordinates is disabled. When i select the checkbox the text input works fine, Search Location is disabled and Coordinates is editable. However, when i try to unselect the checkbox, Search Location is still disabled and Coordinates can still be edited.

I have tried using useEffect but im not too familiar with this nor do i know if this is the correct approach. I am using react hook forms for user inputs and i use react native elements for checkboxes.

Code:

```
export default function UserInput({ navigation }) {
const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
const [checkbox, setCheck] = useState(false);
const [edit1, setEdit1] = useState(true);
const [edit2, setEdit2] = useState(false);

const onSelect = () => {
if (!checkbox) {
  setEdit1(false);
  setEdit2(true);
}
setCheck(!checkbox);
};

return (
<View style={styles.formContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.text}>Distance(km)</Text>
  <Controller
    name="distance"
    control={control}
    rules={{
      required: true,
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Enter your Distance"
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
    )}
  />

  <Text style={styles.text}>Search Location</Text>
  <Controller
    name="searchLocation"
    control={control}
    rules={{
      required: true,
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Enter your Coordinates"
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChange}
        value={value}
        editable={edit1}
      />
    )}
  />
  <CheckBox
    center
    title="Current Location"
    checked={checkbox}
    onPress={onSelect}
  />

  <Text style={styles.text}>Coordinates</Text>
  <Controller
    name="coordinates"
    control={control}
    rules={{
      required: true,
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Enter your Coordinates"
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChange}
        value={value}
        editable={edit2}
      />
    )}
  />
</View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
const onSelect = () => {
if (!checkbox) {
  setEdit1(false);
  setEdit2(true);
} else {
  setEdit1(true);
  setEdit2(false);
}
setCheck(!checkbox);
};
```

Comment: I was over complicating things, thanks